# make incorrectly answered question have unanswered status

Tags: feature-request

I think there should be some way to make any "incorrectly answered question" have "unanswered" status.  Just because someone has responded to a question doesn't mean that it is worthwhile.  In fact, many such "quick" answers are not well thought out.

(Or have I misunderstood?  Do questions remain "unanswered" until an answer is accepted.  If so, it would be good to have a flag that the answer was, shall we say, "insufficient".)

Comment: Is it just me, or are there two of you? It looks like there are two Mark T's, with the same user description, same hometown, same Gravatar even... huh?

Comment: Related: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1251/unanswered-questions-that-are-answered-without-upvotes-or-accepted-answers

Comment: Well, let's consider some of the possibilities.  Perhaps I am beside myself?  Or perhaps schizophrenic?  Identical twins seems less likely.  Or perhaps a "mere reflection of himself"?

More likely, yesterday, when I tried to tie my existing StackOverflow account to my existing SuperUser account, the system made a new account rather than tying them together.

I may have to go to the meta area and ask how to correct it.

Comment: Oddly enough, it looks like your StackOverflow account is associated with both of your SU accounts. Very strange. Might want to ask a Mod to take a look at it and see if both of your accounts could be recombined or something.

Answer (score 4):

Questions you see in the "unanswered" list are questions with **no upvoted answers**. If an answer is incorrect, chances are that it will be either voted down or at least not voted up; as such, those questions will remain in the unanswered list.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It still seems that someone else might up-vote an answer which the original poster found didn't really solve the problem.  I wish there were some way to say "I still need help with this."

Comment: @Mark - "I still need help with this" is accomplished by re-editing a question (to add more info, your own progress, etc), this bumps it up the active questions list. Alternatively you can do this by offering a bounty, which places the question on the featured list (at the cost of some reputation points). And, the `Community` bot/user bumps old questions automatically every so often.