# Who accepts the question in case the the creator deleted the account?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, accepted-answer

I have this current situation on the question [How change the IP address of the computer on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1735814/)

It seems that the creator has deleted their account. Who will be able to accept the answer? Will it be a zombie question forever?

Comment: No one can accept the question except the person who posted it. Potential duplicate: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11081/should-we-the-community-be-able-to-accept-an-answer-on-the-ops-behalf

Comment: The person who posted the question has not followed the migration from Server Fault. If they follow the migration and create an account at [su] and log in with the same details then they will gain control of the question.

Comment: In Conclusion, that means, that the question will be unmarked until the end of universe?

Comment: @djdomi Not necessarily. The author may decide to create an account at Super User anytime.

Comment: Will the user that created the question still receive updates on activity on their question at the new SE site? If not, this might be a good way to get them to create that account and become more active.

Comment: @MiG the asker will have gotten a notification that their question was migrated in the same "mailbox" on the top bar that you see comment and answer notifications in.  Beyond that they dont have an account here so won't see more than that as we have nothing to send them to. If they have turned on email notifications in their account they may also see the migration notification there.

Comment: I'm aware, was referring to activity on that specific migrated post on the new site, might draw them into registering. But I suppose you'd run into technical limitations trying to achieve that.

Comment: Why do you think that answers have to be accepted?  They don't.  There are thousands of questions with perfectly good answers that aren't accepted.

Comment: because this is the way, how this site works. Ask a Question, and Accept it - it does repeat cover up the question, in case the question is not answered. and repeat it until it got accepted. So, Who will accept this - that is the question?! :)

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that the creator has deleted their account.

@djdomi No, the user *does* have a [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/users/20484972/harry?tab=accounts) account that they've used to log in to both Server Fault and Stack Overflow.  However, they've never used it here on Super User.

And from your comment:

> In Conclusion, that means, that the question will be unmarked until the end of universe?

Again, no.  Since the question was migrated from Server Fault to here on SU, they'll simply need to log-in once here on SU using their existing credentials, and then they can accept an answer (or comment) if they so choose.  They will be the owner of that question.

Of course, sometimes this never happens.

To increase the chances of it happening, when I see a migrated question like this from a relatively new or inexperienced Stack user, I usually leave a comment explaining the process, and I'll do so on that question.

Comment: but, still not 100 percent solved, what, if it never happened? this point is still not cleared ;)

Comment: @djdomi we have several hundred thousand questions on this site alone and a good percentage of those have unaccepted answers even when the original poster is active here. No one is obliged or forced to accept an answer beyond the warm fuzzy feeling of giving someone some fake Internet points.

Comment: sorry, but this does not cover the question and use case. This site imho is made for ask and accept a selected answer. if it will not accepted, the question will be re-roled up even after years to get an Answer and furthermore to accept that one. Even there are more. But i think this can imho only solved by the Original Inventors of the site.